# Need some help for better understanding of the code

Tags: node.js, express

This is a working code so just need to understand some parts will be helpful.

upload.js::

```
const util = require("util");
const multer = require("multer");
const GridFsStorage = require("multer-gridfs-storage");
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Grid = require('gridfs-stream');

const mongoURI ='mongodb://localhost:27017/file_uploaded_new';
const promise = mongoose.connect(mongoURI, { useNewUrlParser: true });
const conn = mongoose.connection;
**let gfs;
conn.once('open',() => {
  gfs = Grid(conn, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
});**

**var storage = new GridFsStorage({**
    db: promise,
    **options: {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true }**,
    file: (req, file) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            if (file.mimetype === 'application/vnd.openxmlformats- 
   officedocument.wordprocessingml.document') {
                resolve({
                    bucketName: 'words',
                    filename: `${file.originalname}`
                })
            } else {
                reject(Error("File type has been rejected"));
            }
        });    
    }
});

**var uploadFile = multer({storage: storage}).single("file");**

**var uploadFilesMiddleware = util.promisify(uploadFile);
module.exports = uploadFilesMiddleware;**
```

Need to know specifically the bold part of the code. Got the source code but without explanation. So would really be helpful to understand it.

Comment: Looks like a module for storing uploaded files to MongoDB with GridFS. A good start would be to check the documentation of the dependencies of this code.

Comment: conn.once('open',() => {
  gfs = Grid(conn, mongoose.mongo);
  gfs.collection('uploads');
});

I need to know useof this line...and below line

var uploadFile = multer({storage: storage}).single("file");**

**var uploadFilesMiddleware = util.promisify(uploadFile);